# Ruby on Rails Paypal 2 Payments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

I am creating a website, that allows the users to buy an item. I can do that fine. But my problem is that I would like 10% of what item the user purchase to go to one paypal account, and the remaining 90% to go another paypal account. Is this possible to do in ruby on rails?

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is a Chained Payment, or a Parallel Payment in Paypal speak. There is a subtle difference in the funds flow using each method, but either method will do what you ask.

Both are available using Adaptive Payments and the Classic or Rest APIs for Ruby will enable you to handle either with ease.